# How to make content of <td> invisible except for the left column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

Array of days is formed in a table via javascript.

[image: calendar style table screenshot]

I want to make the `<td>`'s inside `<tbody data-bind="foreach: prayerData">` invisible. I need each `<td>` to carry the value shown like Mon-1, Thrs-1 and so forth but hide them so that they won't be visible. I've no idea how to do this via css or javascript.

HTML:

```
<table class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 text-center columns responsive">
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>F</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: prayerData">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: index"></td>  <!-- Display the current row -->
            <td data-bind="text: M"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: T"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: W"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: T"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: F"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
var dataFromServer = {
    "Morn.": {
        "M": "Mon-1",
        "T": "Tue-1",
        "W": "Wed-1",
        "T": "Thrs-1",
        "F": "Fri-1"
    },
    "Noon": {
        "M": "Mon-2",
        "T": "Tue-2",
        "W": "Wed-2",
        "T": "Thrs-2",
        "F": "Fri-2"
    },
    "Even.": {
         "M": "Mon-3",
        "T": "Tue-3",
        "W": "Wed-3",
        "T": "Thrs-3",
        "F": "Fri-3"
    }
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    //map data to an array
    var mappedToArray = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        mappedToArray.push(item);
        item.index = index;
    });

    this.prayerData = ko.observableArray(mappedToArray);          
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(dataFromServer));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
<style>
tbody[data-bind="foreach: prayerData"] tr td:not(:first-child) {
   color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @sidehowbarker, works...but is there a way where I can show the left columns, the Morn., Noon, and Even. word?

Comment: About showing the first cell (`td`) in each row but not the other cells in each row, see my updated answer.

Comment: Vani, you might also want to edit/update your original question to include the requirement that you want to “show the left columns, the Morn., Noon, and Even.” labels but not show the contents of the other cells in each row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your `CSS` file the following lines of code:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

And then in your `HTML` file, the following line of code:

```
<td class="hidden"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

give an id or class name to the `td`.You can use `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;` . See the example below

class

```
.div{

 visibility:hidden; //or display:none;

}
```

Id

```
#div{

  visibility:hidden;  //or display:none;

}
```